Why is Maven fetching old versions of parent dependencies instead of the latest ones?
I have a project with two Java packages:

Package 1 (Parent)
Package 2 (Child) depends on Package 1.

The child package includes the parent as a dependency in its pom.xml. However, when I build the child package, it is fetching the older version of the parent dependencies, even though I've updated them to the latest versions.
Here’s what I’ve checked so far:

Verified that the parent package has been updated to the correct version.
Cleaned and rebuilt the parent package using mvn clean install.
Double-checked the child pom.xml to ensure it is pointing to the latest parent version.
Used mvn dependency:tree to inspect which versions are being pulled.
Also tried by deleting the mvn repository folder.

Despite these efforts, Maven still resolves and fetches the older versions of the parent dependencies.
Here is pom.xml of child
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>com.project.datalake</groupId>
    <artifactId>service-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.project.datalake</groupId>
<artifactId>service-gcp-cloud</artifactId>
<version>1.1</version>

<name>GCP service</name>
<description>GCP cloud provider</description>

<scm>
    <tag>service-gcp-service-1.1</tag>
</scm>

<properties>
    <lombok.version>1.18.8</lombok.version>
    <mapstruct.version>1.3.0.Final</mapstruct.version>
    <com.google.auth.version>1.22.0</com.google.auth.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.project.datalibrary</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-datalib</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>33.0.0-jre</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.auth</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-auth-library-oauth2-http</artifactId>
        <version>${com.google.auth.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-script</artifactId>
        <version>v1-rev175-1.23.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20231013</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.25.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
                    <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.31.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
        <version>1.35.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-cloudresourcemanager</artifactId>
        <version>v1beta1-rev561-1.25.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-dataproc</artifactId>
        <version>v1-rev150-1.25.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-deploymentmanager</artifactId>
        <version>v2-rev75-1.25.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-compute</artifactId>
        <version>v1-rev235-1.25.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-iam</artifactId>
        <version>v1-rev247-1.23.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
        <version>4.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.10.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-iam-admin</artifactId>
        <version>3.27.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
        <version>1.110.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>gax-grpc</artifactId>
        <version>2.34.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>gax-httpjson</artifactId>
        <version>2.34.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-datastream</artifactId>
        <version>1.32.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-dms</artifactId>
        <version>2.33.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-api-services-bigquery</artifactId>
        <version>v2-rev459-1.25.0</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>1.18.8</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                        <version>0.2.0</version>
                    </path>
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>

and this is the pom.xml of parent
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>commons-datalib</artifactId>
<version>2.0</version>

<name>common packages and utilities.</name>
<description>common libraries and packages.</description>

<scm>
    <tag>commons-datalib-2.0</tag>
</scm>

<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>

        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.93</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-openfeign -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.10.4</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-ldap</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.openfeign</groupId>
        <artifactId>feign-okhttp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.20</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>


Can you please provide details about how you linked the dependency in pom.xml, where is your compiled .jar file located and what path is shown in External Libraries/Maven Dependencies of project tool window?

point #4: whats the result of that? its not clear from you description. Does it show the newer or the older version?

I've checked in the dependency tree and there older version of Package 1 is present

You have many dependencies in there (some of which shouldn't even be there as those are managed by Spring Boot). Which dependency isn't resolving? Please add the pom.xml of the parent also.

I've added both poms

Both your poms are flawed, you are mixing versions of frameworks (Spring BOot 2.3.0 and 2.3.4, your parent should use spring-boot-starter-parent as its parent for proper/better management). If that isn't for you then at least at the dependencies bom as a dependencyManagement section. Your child is flawed (as well as the parent) to include versions of jars that it shouldn't include with versions (like jackson).

Also the pom isn't of the parent it is of a dependency. So I think you are mixing stuff up here in your question.

Thank you for your help. After adding dependencies inside DependencyManagement. My problem was resolved.

If you are using Intellij Idea then try to invalidate caches and then retry.
Sometimes these caches are the reason the dependencies are not resolved properly even after doing the changes in the pom.

No, it's still showing the older version of the dependencies

Can you please help with the child and parent package in the above pom and the exact version you are getting and the expected version.

I've added both poms
